# Creating slider or carousel for bundle product in magento?

Tags: magento

I want to create a bundle products for my estore but the bundle product has more than 50 products

So i want to add carousel or slider to these product. I tried adding some sliders but it is not working??

Please suggest me with some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Got this code from inchoo, so should work

```
$bundled_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(YOUR_BUNDLED_PRODUCT_ID);
$selectionCollection = $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
    $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundled_product), $bundled_product
);
$bundled_items = array();
foreach($selectionCollection as $option)
{
    $bundled_items[] = $option->product_id;
}
print_r($bundled_items);
```

$bundled_items has all the product ids, so you can simple load the product, and get all the detailed info. So Simply provide the data as per the need of the carousel.

To load the product

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PUT_ID_HERE);
```